# Bourbon vs Twitter Bootstrap for Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby-on-rails-3.1, stylesheet, twitter-bootstrap

I am looking around at different stylesheet frameworks to pick out which one to use in my Rails 3.1 applicaiton. Twitter Bootstrap looks really cool, but I also see that Bourbon is becoming very popular too.

Can anyone give a comparison and pros and cons of each?

I am guessing it won't be a good idea to use them both, right?

Comment: I found this gem to use Twitter Bootstrap with rails 3.1: https://github.com/metaskills/less-rails-bootstrap

Comment: Since Bootstrap uses LESS, I am trying to figure out how to change the link colors in it. Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could absolutely use both... Each are a set of SASS mix-ins and CSS classes.

You may run into some overlap, but there's nothing that prevents you from using both